# Is it necessary to install HSQL in hibernate instead of MYSQL as a DATABASE?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hsqldb

For hibernate projects with database. we Must install HSQL. Can the same work will be done through MYSQL also. It is necessary to install HSQL with hibernate in java instead of MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Hiberante is a [ORM framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). it's not depend on any database.

Answer (score 0):

No its not necessary to use `HSQL` for the same. You can use `MySql` too. You will just need to configure it using the respective drivers as explained at this [link](http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/60-hibernate-with-mysql-a-beginners-guide)

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate you can use the same code to connect to both HSQL, MySQL or others databases. You will only need to change your jdbc connectors configuration and use the corresponding jdbc library.